# 1d complex to complex transform with cuda cufft library

Tags: cuda, fft, dft, cufft

i'm writing a simple code for complex to complex 1d FFT with cuda library "cufft". I've changed "cudaMalloc" with "malloc" because if i use cudaMalloc exe file not work and crashing! But this is not the primary problem.
When i execute the program, cufftExecC2C return a value != CUFFT_SUCCESS so FFT not work!! why?
this is my code

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <cufft.h>
  #include <cuda.h>
  #include <math.h>


  #define NX 64
  #define BATCH 1
  #define PI 3.14159265
  #define FREQ 10


  int main(){


//dichiarazione delle variabili
cufftHandle plan; 
cufftComplex *out;
cufftComplex *in;
char premi_invio;
int i;


//assegnazione memoria agli array in e out
in=(cufftComplex*)malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);
/*
if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess){
printf("Cuda error: allocazione fallita\n");
return;
};
*/

out=(cufftComplex*)malloc(sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);
/*
if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess){
printf("Cuda error: allocazione fallita\n");
return;
};
*/

//creazione del piano per la trasformata e controllo della corretta creazione del piano
if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH) == CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    printf("piano creato correttamente!\npremi invio per continuare...\n");
    scanf("%c", &premi_invio);
};

//assegnazione campioni all'array di input

for (i = 0; i < NX; i++){
    in[i].x = cos(2 * PI * FREQ * i / NX);
    in[i].y = 0;
};
printf("Vuoi visualizzare i campioni? (y/n)\n");
scanf("%c", &premi_invio);
if (premi_invio == 'y'){
    for (i = 0; i < NX; i++){
        printf("in[%d].x = %f \tin[%d].y = %f \n", i, in[i].x, i, in[i].y);
    }
}

//esecuzione trasformata e controllo della corretta esecuzione
if (cufftExecC2C(plan,in,out,CUFFT_FORWARD) == CUFFT_SUCCESS){
    printf("trasformata eseguita correttamente!\npremi invio per vedere i risultati...\n");
    scanf("%c", &premi_invio);}
else {
    printf("trasformata non eseguita\nPremi invio per tornare...\n");
    scanf("%c", &premi_invio);
    return;
}
//visualizzazione risultati (vettore out)
for (i = 0; i < NX; i++){
    printf("out[%d].x = %f \tout[%d].y = %f\n", i, cuCrealf(out[i]),i, cuCimagf(out[i]) );

}

cufftDestroy(plan);
//cudaFree(in);
//cudaFree(out);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [explains](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftexecc2c-cufftexecz2z) that the input and output data must be on the GPU, so you need to use `cudaMalloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

SO the real question is why you had a problem when using `cudaMalloc()`; probably the simplest explanation is that you were allocating GPU memory and then trying to write to it directly in the CPU code:

```
for (i = 0; i < NX; i++){
  in[i].x = cos(2 * PI * FREQ * i / NX);
  in[i].y = 0;
};
```

Instead you should `malloc()` the same size region on the CPU, initialise this region on the CPU and then use `cudaMemcpy()` to copy it to the GPU. Likewise to copy the results back to read them. Ideally, of course, you would leave the data on the GPU for further processing!